# Looping over characters in Fortran

Tags: loops, fortran

I would like to know if it is possible to loop over strings in Fortran. For example I would like to know if the following code:

```
DO p=a,b,c,t,r
  ...
END DO
```

would replace a b c t and r whenever a p is writen.

Comment: Okay thank you. I completely understand your position. I felt that the previous title ‘Looping over Characters’, is completely unsearchable on the web if anyone else were to encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Or, if by *string* OP means a character variable of length `n`, one might have something like

```
character(len=n) :: string
...
string = 'abcdef'
...
do i = 1,n
   write(*,*) string(i:i)
end do
```

noting that for taking substrings of any length (including `1`) both start and end indices have to be supplied

Answer (score 4):

A loop index is always a scalar integer.  Fortunately it's a simple enough matter to use an array of the desired "iterated" objects:

```
character, parameter :: ps(*) = ['a', 'b', 'c', 't', 'r']
integer i
character p

do i=1, SIZE(ps)
  p = ps(i)
  ...
end do
```

This idiom holds for more than just characters.