# Smart way to have a Fortran do loop over seperate ranges of the same variable

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Imagine I have a do loop over a variable, I. Typically this variable has a range of 1-20 but I want to create a do loop over the range 1-5 and 8-12. I can't create a simple do loop because the ranges are not consecutive. I don't want to put a logic statement in because I don't want to slow anything down. What would be a smart or creative way to execute this loop and can it be done without a logic statement?

Comment: Besides two `do` loops?

Comment: You can essentially follow the approach described in answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47581965/3157076): create an array with you desired indices and then select over those in the loop.  Better than a `cycle`?

Comment: Between the two linked questions you hopefully find enough to address your problem.  One question's answers look at skipping iterations using logic, including modifying the "loop counter"; the other has an array to be indexed over.

Comment: Or with `i=1,5` use `j=i+7`